# JSONP no get value result

Tags: c#, json, jsonp

I'm doing a project for college where one WebSite sends commands to a Windows Forms application. This application is responsible for access to serial port and send and receive commands.

Communication between the Website and the Windows Forms application, I used Web Api, however after publishing, auditioning remembered that the localhost in a C # WebSite. Net's own site and not my Windows Forms application.

I changed the call to the Web Api directly use Ajax and not a controller.
In the examples I found I saw that I use JSONP, but I can not read the results and use it on my website.

The calling code and return seen by Chrome are below

```
function cmdLocal() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://local host:8089/api/gps/",
        jsonpCallback: "cmdTorre",
        jsonp: "cmdTorre"
    });             
}

function cmdTorre(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Response Header

```
Content-Length:10
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 10 Jun 2014 11:18:30 GMT
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

Response

```
No Properties
```

Windows Forms APIController

```
namespace TCCWindows.Lib
{
    public class GPSController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Posicao()
        {
            var coordenada = TCCWindows.FormPrincipal.PegarCoordenadas();
            return coordenada.Latitude + "|" + coordenada.Longitude + "|" + coordenada.Altitude;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you ajax call looks overly complicated try replacing it with :

```
function cmdLocal() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://local host:8089/api/gps/",
        success: cmdTorre,
        error: function(err){
           alert("You have a error"+err);
        }
    });             
}

function cmdTorre(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Please validate the new code carefully. I just typed it in here so can have errors. If this runs at this point you should probably see the error message. That is because your `GPSController` doesnt seem to be returning a valid JSONP (or JSON for that matter). Please read up on JSONP for more clarification but, I think if you modify your return statement to make it look like following, it should work. Assuming your controller is actually getting called and your network stuff is working:

```
 return "cmdTorre({\"lat\":"+coordenada.Latitude+" , \"lon\":"+coordenada.Longitude+" });"
```

Basically your return string should look like following when printed on console:

```
function cmdTorre({
    "lat": 23.34,
    "lon":34.23,
    "alt":50
});
```

Again I suggest you check the code I wrote for syntax issues as i just typed it up in here, but it should give you the idea.

So problems were:

1. The return string you are generating is NOT in JSON format
2. It is also not wrapped in a function call making it a invalid JSONP too.

Lastly my solution should get your code working and JSONP started but its not the right way to do things. Its more of a ugly hack. Your GPS controller should read the HTTP request for parameter called `'callback'` which is a accepted convention for JSONP calls. Then instead of hardcoding the function name in the return statement, you should use the value of this callback parameter. Then you dont need to use a specific function like 'cmdTorre' in your jQuery. Instead a anonymus function like `success:function(response){...}` will work just fine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The result was in Chrome get browse:

    <Coordenada xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TCCWindows.Model">
    <Altitude i:nil="true"/>
    <Latitude>123</Latitude>
    <Longitude>456</Longitude>
    </Coordenada>

With Network Chrome working, JQuery but still gives error ... I do not know why

Comment: is that after modifying the return statement to the one i showed?

Comment: I modified the controller to send:
[code]
        [HttpGet]
        public Coordenada Posicao()
        {
            return TCCWindows.FormPrincipal.PegarCoordenadas();
        }
[/code]
and

public class Coordenada
    {
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Altitude { get; set; }
    }

sorry I tried but I could not put indented